# how to set timeout of query in codeigniter

Tags: php, postgresql, codeigniter, query-timeout

I want to set query timeout if it takes more than 5 seconds. I have tried `$db['default']['options'] = array(PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 5);`
code but it closes the connection.
Is there any workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Attribute to PDO connection in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37467261/how-to-set-attribute-to-pdo-connection-in-codeigniter)